# How to load bash command history from file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, history

I am moving from one server to another, but want to keep my history, so I dumped it into a file.

history > file.txt

Is there a way to overwrite the commands-history of bash and load it from a file?

Comment: simply copy your `$HOME/.bash_histroy` file and youre done... Don't need the "export".

Comment: For some reason it seems that my .bash_history file is not getting updated. This might be related for the fact I use a grid gateway that has a common file system with other gateways. In any case. The accepted answer below solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: strange, just tried `scp .bash_history my@panda:~` and logged in to panda and got my history. IMHO probably because you tried replace it _in the current shell_, and when you logged out the `savehist` overwrite the file with the current history.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The following will append the contents of `file.txt` to the current in-memory history list:

```
history -r file.txt
```

You can optionally run `history -c` before this to clear the in-memory history.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to edit this file and paste everything in there:

emacs -nw ~/.bash_history

Here's an interesting post about the command-history:
http://www.ducea.com/2006/05/15/linux-tips-take-control-of-your-bash_history/